# How to write UPDATE query to use two columns from other table that are from same random row?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table TableA with several columns. I would like to update each row in TableA so that the first two columns of each row are randomly selected from the first two columns of TableB. However, I cannot use something like

```
update TableA
    set col1 = (select top 1 col1 from TableB order by newid()),
        col2 = (select top 1 col2 from TableB order by newid())
```

because I need the two columns from TableB to be from the same randomly selected row. How can I write a query to make sure that the two columns from TableB are from the same row?

Comment: Do you wish your randomly selected row data from TableB to be copied to **all** rows of TableA, or should a new random selection take place for each row in TableA?

Comment: A new random selection should take place for each row in TableA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way is to write your random values into a temporary table, since the point of a random value function is that either it returns a different value each time you call it (resulting in different rows selected for `col1` and `col2`) or it returns the same value for a given seed (which would make all rows in `TableA` to have the same values for only one randomly selected row from `TableB`).

The below SQL code assumes that you have an identity column `id` on `TableA`, but you can easily modify it.

```
-- make temporary table to use row numbers for TableA
select id, row_number() over (order by $/0) as [row] into #a from TableA;
-- make enough copies of TableB to have same number of rows as TableA
with n as
(
    select distinct n = number
           from [master]..spt_values
           where number between 1 and floor((select count(*) from TableA) / (select count(*) from TableB))
)
select b.col1, b.col2, row_number() over (order by newid()) as [row]
into #TableBRandom
from (
    select col1, col2 from TableB, n
    union all
    select top ((select count(*) from TableA) % (select count(*) from TableB)) col1, col2 from TableB
) b
-- update TableA
update TableA
    set col1 = (select top 1 col1 from #TableBRandom where [row] = (select [row] from #a where #a.id = TableA.id)),
        col2 = (select top 1 col2 from #TableBRandom where [row] = (select [row] from #a where #a.id = TableA.id))
```

Comment: Note that this will work only if `floor((select count(*) from TableA) / (select count(*) from TableB))` is at most `2048`.